# Can't create virtual machine in ESXI 6.5 web gui

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, esxi

I'm trying to create a virtual machine in the ESXI 6.5 web gui, but it always fails with the following error:

```
Failed - File [datastore1] pfSense/pfSense_0.vmdk was not found
File system specific implementation of Lookup[file] failed
File system specific implementation of Lookup[file] failed
File system specific implementation of Lookup[file] failed
File system specific implementation of Lookup[file] failed
File system specific implementation of Lookup[file] failed
File system specific implementation of Lookup[file] failed
File system specific implementation of LookupAndOpen[file] failed
File system specific implementation of Lookup[file] failed
File system specific implementation of Lookup[file] failed
File system specific implementation of Lookup[file] failed
File system specific implementation of Lookup[file] failed
File system specific implementation of Lookup[file] failed
```

pfSense is the name I gave the VM. If I try to create the virtual machine in the deprecated 5.5 vSphere client it works, so it seems something specific to the web gui.

I hope someone can help me.

Best regards,
Markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the newest embedded host client fling fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks, that did it for me!